# extending abstract class in realm giving error

Tags: java, android, realm

i have a class A

```
public  abstract class A extends RealmObject{

}

public class B extends A {

}
```

error: A RealmClass annotated object must be derived from RealmObject

Comment: visit [link]( https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/440)

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, subclassing a subclass of RealmObject isn´t supported by Realm in Android for the moment, but there's already a feature in their roadmap in order to improve this point ( https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/761 ).

At least, you can always duplicate fields between model classes, to simulate subclassing (not very elegant though).

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is not supported (answer based on v1.1.0), only interface implementation is.

Answer (score -1):

To me I solved this issue by removing the dependency.

```
compile 'io.realm:realm-android:1.1.0'
```

and put the class path as:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.1.0"
}
}
```

and also put plugin as:

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

Further you can visit to [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/)